# what happens to uploaded files after navigation away from a page in php?

Tags: php

I have a form page that posts to another page where multiple fields as well as file uploads are processed.  Just wondering what happens to the 'tmp_name' files when/if the user enters some incorrect info and I send them back to the form page with a meta refesh?

If successful, I move the file to a new location. But if not successful, do the files get unset or erased if the user gets redirected?  If they don't, can I reaccess them again so the user doesnt have to reupload?  OTOH if there is a problem with the file, say it is not the expected MIME type, should I unlink($_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name']?  Its easy to force the user to re-upload again, i think, but I dont want the server being filled up with files that will never be used?  If the form passes inspection, and I use rename() to move the file, is the temp file really gone?  Did it ever exist on the server's hard drive, or was it only in RAM? Whats the best practice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do the files get unset or erased if the user gets redirected?

The uploaded files are stored in the `/tmp` directory (or whatever is specified as PHP's temporary location). Once your script has run, files left there are subject to deletion any time. I don't think they usually get deleted straight away, but the contents of `/tmp` will be automatically purged by the OS when necessary.

`/tmp` is usually located on a hard drive, not in RAM.

Managing this is usually nothing you need to worry about.

> If the form passes inspection, and I use rename() to move the file, is the temp file really gone?

Yes, but you **must** use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) on uploaded files instead of  `rename()` for security reasons.

Comment: PHP auto-removes the uploaded files when the script exits, unless you've dealt with them yourself.

Comment: @Marc B ah, fair enough. Never knew what exactly happened here - like Sabeen, I thought it was the OS's temporary file functionality taking over. Thanks!

Comment: Marc, Ok, so that means on a meta refresh to a new page that the files are deleted. So that means I can't keep the tmp file alive and reuse it if the user has to fill out the form again, unless I actually save it somewhere else right? So in other words, unless I explicitly save the file, the user will have to reupload it again?

Comment: @Ralphie: exactly. It's not too hard to move it somewhere and store its location/name in the user's session. You'd have to roll your own cleanup script to handle any orphaned files, though (e.g. user uploads file, but never proceeds to the next stage of your processing workflow).

Answer (score 1):

<s>The file is stored in the tmp folder and if you don't move it elsewhere it will stay there. It will be removed automatically by the OS on next cleanup.</s>

Edit:
Please look at Marc's comment below.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> The file will be deleted from the
>   temporary directory at the end of the
>   request if it has not been moved away
>   or renamed.

Comment: OK.  How often on average does cleanup occur?  What if it happens to happen right after the processing script has been run?  Is the file gone then?  should I always just move these files to my own temporary folder until I know for sure the user is done with it?  Whats best practice?

Comment: It's PHP that does the autoremoval when the script exits. The underlying OS has no way of knowing it's a "temporary" file.

Comment: Thank you @MarcB for correcting that. I always thought that on reboot or `tmpwatch` would remove the orphaned files from `/tmp` . @raplhie I think that alone should clear up your question.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that PHP/Apache could die hard enough that PHP doesn't do the cleanup, leaving some orphans. But unless the session files are going into a monitored system tmp folder (e.g. the real /tmp), the OS won't do the cleanup either.

Comment: @MarcB .. yes that makes complete sense